# get coordinates of selected vertex of mesh and plot them in matplotlib

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

i want to get the coordinates of every selected vertex in blender and plot them in maptlotlib in python.
My current code is

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bm = bmesh.new()
ob = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)

def draw_multiple_points():
    x_number_list = []  
    y_number_list = [] 
    for v in bm.verts:
        if v.select:
            print(tuple(v.co) )
            tup = tuple(v.co)
            x = tup[1] #y
            y = tup[2] #z
            #x = p[0]
            print(x,y,)
            print("yz")
            # x axis value list.
            x_number_list.append(x)
            y_number_list.append(y)
        # y axis value list.
    # Draw point based on above x, y axis values.
    print(x_number_list,y_number_list)
    plt.scatter(x_number_list, y_number_list)
    # Set chart title.
    plt.title("Nums")
    # Set x, y label text.
    plt.xlabel("Right")
    plt.ylabel("Top")
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig(rf'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\save.png')
    x_number_list.clear()
    y_number_list.clear()
    
draw_multiple_points()
```

When i try to run the code for a simple mesh like this
[image: On a simple Mesh it works]
it works
[image: Here it works]
But when i try to run the code for a more Complicated Mesh like a Person
[image: it dont work]
the plot completly distorts.
so can anyone help?
i have blender 3.0 and python 3.9.7

Comment: Are you ignoring the z location? Also, it seems like you are using yz instead of xy. The index of the x axis is zero and not 1.

Comment: It's not necessarily your problem but you should add `bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()` before you iterate over `bm.verts`